# How to iterate org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue which is an array of JSON objects to separately work on each object in Scala?

Tags: json, scala, json4s

I have a sample array:

```
[{
    "abc":"1",
    "de":"1"
},
{
    "fgh":"2",
    "ij":"4"
}]
```

which is a org.json4s.JsonAST.JValue.

How is it possible to iterate over each object inside the array, to operate on each object separately?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The following is your json.

```
scala> json
res2: org.json4s.JValue = JArray(List(JObject(List((abc,JString(1)), (de,JString(1)))),
        JObject(List((fgh,JString(2)), (ij,JString(4))))))
```

There are several ways.

1. use `for` syntax

   ```
   for {
     JArray(objList) <- json
     JObject(obj) <- objList
   } {
     // do something
     val kvList = for ((key, JString(value)) <- obj) yield (key, value)
     println("obj : " + kvList.mkString(","))
   }
   ```
2. convert to `scala.collection` object

   ```
   val list = json.values.asInstanceOf[List[Map[String, String]]]
   //=> list: List[Map[String,String]] = List(Map(abc -> 1, de -> 1), Map(fgh -> 2, ij -> 4))
   ```

   or

   ```
   implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
   val list = json.extract[List[Map[String,String]]]
   //=> list: List[Map[String,String]] = List(Map(abc -> 1, de -> 1), Map(fgh -> 2, ij -> 4))
   ```

   and do something.

   ```
   for (obj <- list) println("obj : " + obj.toList.mkString(","))
   ```

Both outputs are

```
obj : (abc,1),(de,1)
obj : (fgh,2),(ij,4)
```

The document of json4s is [here](https://github.com/json4s/json4s#querying-json).

Comment: Could you help to explain how this pattern matching works? t.filter( a => { a match { case JArray(b) => println(b) ; case other => println(other) }  ; true })  . It returns 7 matches. 
List(JObject(List((abc,JString(1)), (de,JString(1)))), JObject(List((fgh,JString(2)), (ij,JString(4)))))
JObject(List((abc,JString(1)), (de,JString(1))))
JString(1)
JString(1)
JObject(List((fgh,JString(2)), (ij,JString(4))))
JString(2)
JString(4)

Answer (score 7):

You should be able to either cast to JArray

```
val myArray = myVal.asInstanceOf[JArray]
myArray.arr // the array
```

or preferably use a scala match so you can confirm the type is correct.

Comment: I was about to get into a scala match nightmare to solve this. Like this, it's just perfect.